# Could not attach GCE PD, Timeout waiting for mount paths

Tags: mongodb, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

this is getting out of hand... have good specs of GKE, yet, I'm getting timeout for mount paths, I have posted this issue in github, but they said, it would be better if posted in SO. please fix this..

```
2m      2m      1   {scheduler }                                        Scheduled   Successfully assigned mongodb-shard1-master-gp0qa to gke-cluster-1-micro-a0f27b19-node-0p2j
1m      1m      1   {kubelet gke-cluster-1-micro-a0f27b19-node-0p2j}    FailedMount Unable to mount volumes for pod "mongodb-shard1-master-gp0qa_default": Could not attach GCE PD "shard1-node1-master". Timeout waiting for mount paths to be created.
1m      1m      1   {kubelet gke-cluster-1-micro-a0f27b19-node-0p2j}    FailedSync  Error syncing pod, skipping: Could not attach GCE PD "shard1-node1-master". Timeout waiting for mount paths to be created.
```

Comment: Does `/var/log/kubelet.log` on that node give any hints as to why the PD failed to attach/mount?

Comment: I am seeing the same issue.  When I look at the kubelet log, I see:  Error attaching PD "disk1": googleapi: Error 404: The resource 'proj
ects/myproject' was not found, notFound

Comment: Is this issue resolved? If so, can you post an answer to mention how did you fix it. This can help other people who are (will be) experiencing the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

This problem has been documented several times, for example here https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/14642. Kubernetes v1.3.0 should have a fix.

As a workaround (in GCP) you can restart your VMs.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that your GCE service account may not be authorized on your project. Try re-adding `$YOUR_PROJECT_NUMBER-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com` as "Can-edit" on the [Permissions](https://console.developers.google.com/permissions/projectpermissions) page of the Developers Console.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this recently, and the issue ended up being that the application running inside the docker container was actually shutting down immediately - this caused gce to try and restart it, but it would fail when GCE tried to attach the disk (already attached).

So, seems like a bit of a bug in GCE, but don't run down the rabbit hole trying to figure that out, I ended up running things locally and debugging the crash using local volume mounts.

Answer (score 0):

this is an old question, but I like to share how I fixed the problem. I manually un-mount the problematic disks from its host via the google cloud console.